# Most efficient way to loop through two C# Lists

Tags: c#

I have a method which I call `CalculatePopularityScore`. It exists on a `Story` object. The `Story` object has a field which is an ICollection of Comment objects.

```
public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
```

The `Comment` object has another collection of `Reply` objects.

My method looks at the story, loops through the comments associated with that story, and if the story's comments has replies, adds up that total. That, along with some other fields, gives me a very (and I stress this) very rudimentary algorithm of a story's popularity.

```
public double CalculateStoryPopularityScore()
{
            if (Comments == null) throw new ArgumentException("Comments can't be null");
            if (Comments.Count < 0) throw new ArgumentException("Comments can't be less than zero.");

            int ReplyCountSum = 0;
            double ReplyScore;
            double CommentScore;
            double InsightfulVoteScore;
            double UsefulVoteScore;
            double viewCount;

            foreach (var comment in Comments)
            {
                int replyCount;

                if (comment.Replies == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("Replies cannot be null");
                }

                if (comment.Replies.Count() == 0)
                {
                    replyCount = 0;
                } else
                {
                    replyCount = comment.Replies.Count();
                }

                ReplyCountSum += replyCount;
            }

            ReplyScore = ReplyCountSum * 4;
            CommentScore = Comments.Count() * 4;
            InsightfulVoteScore = InsightFulVoteCount * 3;
            UsefulVoteScore = UsefulVoteCount * 2;
            viewCount = ViewCount;

            double PopularityScore = CommentScore + ReplyScore + InsightfulVoteScore + + UsefulVoteScore + viewCount;
            return PopularityScore;
}
```

This seems to work fine. Now, what I'd like to do is take this method and apply it to a number of stories (i.e. a list).

I currently have this method written. It has not yet implemented another loop to look through the replies to the comments collection of a story. I know nested loops are considered bad and slow. What would be the most efficient way to look at the list of stories, then the list of comments in each story, add up those replies, and calculate a story's popularity score?

```
public void CalculateStoryPopularityScore(List<Story> stories)
{
            if (stories == null) throw new ArgumentException("Stories can't be null");

            double CommentScore;
            double InsightfulVoteScore;
            double UsefulVoteScore;
            double PopularityScore;
            double ViewCount;

            foreach (var story in stories)
            {
                CommentScore = story.Comments.Count() * 4;
                InsightfulVoteScore = story.InsightFulVoteCount * 3;
                UsefulVoteScore = story.UsefulVoteCount * 2;
                ViewCount = story.ViewCount;

                PopularityScore = CommentScore + InsightfulVoteScore + UsefulVoteScore + ViewCount;
                story.PopularityScore = PopularityScore;
            }
}
```

Comment: This sounds like something you should be doing in the DB/DB query, not in the code. A "currentValue" that is updated via a Add/Update Trigger on the Comments table ora view can both be used to cache such data. Doing this operation every time the page is draw or a postback of this page appears is just a massive waste of resources.

Comment: You can also consider using Dictionaries to help avoid inner loops.

Comment: `I know nested loops are considered bad and slow` have you measured? is it really slow for your purposes? How big are your data? And how often this calculation needs to happen?

Comment: Note that I am normally very firmly about "not putting process data into the DB". But something like "StoryPopularityScore" based on comments (often querried, very rarely changed) just screams for some for of caching.

Comment: @trailmax No. I haven't tested for myself. Just from the blogs I've read about O(N²) and the scary looking graph as it escalates quickly. My application is currently small and still very much in development, but what other developers do with it...

Comment: @J.G.Sable in this case you are going into a [premature optimisation](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization). Just have nested loops and be done with it. Yes, the loops will be executed multiple times and you'll a higher order complexity. But with the structure you describe, whatever you do, it'll be nested loops eventually. I'm 100% certain you'll have a bigger fish to fry when it'll come to "oops, my application is slow". But always measure first before you start optimising.

Comment: @trailmax okay. I was just trying to make other developers's jobs more senior than I once I pass my part off a bit easier.

Comment: By the way, it doesn't make any sense to throw an `ArgumentException` from a method that doesn't take any arguments (in the first example). You should probably re-write it so that the `comments` are passed in as a parameter. Also, local variables should be `camelCase`, not `PascalCase` in c#. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `SelectMany`

```
var commentCount = story.Comments.Count();

// count all replies to all comments for a story
var replyCountSum = story.Comments
    .SelectMany(c => c.Replies)
    .Count();
```

Apply to a collection of stories:

```
stories.Select(s => new
{
    Story = s,
    CommentCount = s.Comments.Count(),
    ReplyCount = s.Comments.SelectMany(c => c.Replies).Count(),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, all the scores you're calculating with a separate method can instead be written as a public read-only (calculated) property of the `Story` class. The reply count can be obtained by using `SelectMany` (which is used to flatten lists of lists into a single list) and then getting the `Count` property:

```
public class Story
{
    public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public int InsightFulVoteCount { get; set; }
    public int UsefulVoteCount { get; set; }
    public int ViewCount { get; set; }

    public int PopularityScore
    {
        get
        {
            return
                (Comments?.Count ?? 0) * 4 +
                (Comments?.SelectMany(comment => comment.Replies).Count() ?? 0) * 4 +
                InsightFulVoteCount * 3 +
                UsefulVoteCount * 2 +
                ViewCount;
        }
    }
}

public class Comment
{
    public List<string> Replies { get; set; }
}
```

---

In case you're not familiar with the [null-conditional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) operator (`?.`), it returns `null` if the left operand (the object) is null before accessing the right operand (property or method of the object). If the left side is not null, then the property/method value is returned.

Then the [null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) (`??`) evaluates the left operand (which is the result of the property or method access) and, if it's null, it returns the right operand (`'0'` in our case).

Basically this simplifies the code. You don't have to do:

```
var score = 0;
if (Comments != null) score = Comments.Count;
```

You can just do:

```
var score = Comments?.Count ?? 0;
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm less concerned with the method which revolves around a single story than the method which accepts a list of stories and has to rank them.

Comment: Well after the above you can just do `var rankedStories = stories.OrderByDescending(story => story.PopularityScore);`

Comment: `OrderByDescending` puts the highest rank first. Technically you should be able to use your existing method, too...I just think a property is more readable. To use your existing method you would just do `var ranked = stories.OrderByDescending(s => s.CalculateStoryPopularityScore());`, but you'd want to get rid of the exception throwing part and just return zero instead.